# Javascript for loop parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not very good with Javascript. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
var data = [
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"day of march 2011 to someother numeric"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"this 22nd day of march 2011 to someother string"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"this 22nd day of march 2021 monitor ground fort ord 1990 101"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"forhidden","Column_3":" area to aoid someother douling"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"forhidden","Column_3":" area to aoid someother string forbidden area"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"notpermitted","Column_3":"y of march 2001 monitor ground  not permitted in states 1990 101"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to ","keyw":"aoid","Column_3":" someother douling"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to ","keyw":"aoid","Column_3":" someother string forbidden area"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to aoid someother ","keyw":"douling","Column_3":""},
 {"Column":"this 22nd day of march 2001 ","keyw":"douling","Column_3":" ground fort ord 1990 101"} 
];

var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
//var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

To create a parameter I have to do it manual like this:

```
params = {
  
a: json[0].Column,
aa: json[0].keyw,
aaa: json[0].Column_3,
b: json[1].Column,
bb: json[1].keyw,
bbb: json[1].Column_3,
...
...
...
}
```

Is there a way to make this a kind of loop, or auto?

Greets Mike

Comment: How is `a`, `aa` and `aaa` genrated? Do you need like that or it's just an example and if its an example then what do you need there?

Comment: I use it for a dynamic textbox. I can refer to the parameters like this :
${a} ${aa} ${aaa} 
${b} ${bb} ${bbb}

This way i can get the full sentence

Comment: There is no need to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` because it's not a string (It's a normal array of objects). The only thing you need is the `map` function to transform entries. `data.map(x=>({a: x.Column ...})`.

Comment: There is a sugar way to destruct the first entry: `const [{Column: a}] = data`

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring:

```
for (const item of data) { 
  const { Column, keyw, Column_3, Column } = item;
  console.log(Column); // prints Column variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `repeat()` and keep a alphabet map. The rest is pretty straight forward with dynamic keys using `[]`.

```js
const data = [{
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "",
    "Column_3": "day of march 2011 to someother numeric"
  },
  {
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "",
    "Column_3": "this 22nd day of march 2011 to someother string"
  },
  {
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "",
    "Column_3": "this 22nd day of march 2021 monitor ground fort ord 1990 101"
  },
  {
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "forhidden",
    "Column_3": " area to aoid someother douling"
  },
  {
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "forhidden",
    "Column_3": " area to aoid someother string forbidden area"
  },
  {
    "Column": "",
    "keyw": "notpermitted",
    "Column_3": "y of march 2001 monitor ground  not permitted in states 1990 101"
  },
  {
    "Column": "forhidden area to ",
    "keyw": "aoid",
    "Column_3": " someother douling"
  },
  {
    "Column": "forhidden area to ",
    "keyw": "aoid",
    "Column_3": " someother string forbidden area"
  },
  {
    "Column": "forhidden area to aoid someother ",
    "keyw": "douling",
    "Column_3": ""
  },
  {
    "Column": "this 22nd day of march 2001 ",
    "keyw": "douling",
    "Column_3": " ground fort ord 1990 101"
  }
];


const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

const result = data.map((d, index) => {
  const key = alphabet[index];
  return {
    [key]: d.Column,
    [key.repeat(2)]: d.keyw,
    [key.repeat(3)]: d.Column_3,
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

*Although a caveat here is that the code will break once it reaches the end of the alphabet list. It's upto you to handle that case, since you've not specified the requirement for dynamic keys.*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution similar to PsyGik's

```
var initialASCIIval = 97;
var obj = {};
data.forEach((e) => {
 Object.keys(e).forEach((k, i) => {
  obj[`${String.fromCharCode(initialASCIIval).repeat(i + 1)}`] = e[k];
  });
 initialASCIIval++;
 });
```

What I'm doing is I'm initializing `a`'s ASCII code (since it's the first property in the desired object), then for each element in `data` I iterate over each key of that element and append a new property (i.e. `a`, `aa` etc, hence the usage of `repeat()`) and then I increment `initialASCIIval` to move on to the next alphabet. Of course, depending on your array, this might exceed the ASCII value bound for lowercase alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"day of march 2011 to someother numeric"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"this 22nd day of march 2011 to someother string"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"","Column_3":"this 22nd day of march 2021 monitor ground fort ord 1990 101"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"forhidden","Column_3":" area to aoid someother douling"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"forhidden","Column_3":" area to aoid someother string forbidden area"},
 {"Column":"","keyw":"notpermitted","Column_3":"y of march 2001 monitor ground  not permitted in states 1990 101"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to ","keyw":"aoid","Column_3":" someother douling"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to ","keyw":"aoid","Column_3":" someother string forbidden area"},
 {"Column":"forhidden area to aoid someother ","keyw":"douling","Column_3":""},
 {"Column":"this 22nd day of march 2001 ","keyw":"douling","Column_3":" ground fort ord 1990 101"} 
];

var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

let params = {};

json.map((event, index) => toNewEventObject(event, index))
.forEach(rdata => params = { ...params , ...rdata });

function toNewEventObject({ Column, keyw, Column_3}, index){
    const objKey = generateKey(index);
    return {
     [objKey]: Column,
     [objKey.repeat(2)]: keyw,
     [objKey.repeat(3)]: Column_3,
    };
}

function generateKey(index){
  return String.fromCharCode(97+index);;
}
console.log(params);
```